# Pepper Emulator on Android Studio doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, pepper

I recently tried to install Android-Studio to work on Pepper's robot program but after following all the instructions that I found QISDK I can't start the emulator. I tried everything but it still doesn't work. The event log message is:

```
PATH=C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator;

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib64;

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib;

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib;

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib/qt/lib;

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/qemu Windows-x86_64/qe mu-system-i386.exe -sysdir "

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86 kernel"

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotsSDK\API 6\avd/x86\"kernel-ranchu"-system "

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\system.img"-ramdisk

"C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\ramdisk.img" -data "

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK API 6 avd/x86\userdata.img" -cache

"C Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\userdata.img" -cache

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/cache.img" -skin 1280x800 -ports "5575, 5579" -sdcard

C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RoboSDK\API 6\avd/x86\sd-card.img"-gpu swiftshader_indirect-vendor none
```

I'm working on windows 10 with Android Studio 3.6.3
I already had Java Development Kit (the last one).
I configurated Android Studio with all the information that I found here step by step without missing anything I guess:

https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/getting-started/installing-pepper-sdk-plug

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post more of the error log message? And can you give us some details about your system (OS, Android studio version, et c.). Finally, if you could give us a list of the steps you followed from the QiSDK instructions, that would be great.

Comment: I've just added more information to my previous post.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Known issue:
AVD does not work on Windows 10 with emulator 29.2.1 or higher

Workaround: Downgrade Android studio emulator to version 29.0.11

Download archive https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5598178.zip
Go to repository C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
Replace emulator folder by the emulator in the archive

Link: https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch5_news/known_issues.html